# BIRT Report Design - Setting Parameter for Secondary Dataset

Tags: eclipse, birt, workday-api

I'm hoping this is a simple question from a novice. I'm using BIRT in Workday Studio (based on Eclipse) and I am running into an issue with my secondary data sets. When I set the parameter a the secondary data set and I try to Preview Results, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Data engine operation failed due to an unexpected exception.
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information. There are errors evaluating script "row.__rownum": ReferenceError: "row" is not defined.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:671)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.extractQuery(DatasetPreviewTask.java:349)
```

I was able to build my report and successfully run it until I tried creating a Joint Data Set. I'm receiving the exact same message when I try to create the Joint Data Set.

Any thoughts? I've been using BIRT for years in Workday Studio and I've never run into this before.

-Nathan

Comment: Have you checked if both the individual datasets are getting retrieved individually..( i.e. check if row object is null  for either dataset )?  Are the "row"  object denoted separately...like  row1 for dataset 1 and row 2 for dataset 2?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the __rownum pseudo-column is only availabe for events of layout elements, not for e.g. the DS onFetch events.